# Tree traversals python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree, inorder, preorder, postorder

I have to define three functions: `preorder(t):`, `postorder(t):`, and `inorder(t):`.

Each function will take a binary tree as input and return a list. The list should then be ordered in same way the tree elements would be visited in the respective traversal (post-order, pre-order, or in-order)

I have written a code for each of them, but I keep getting an error when I call another function (`flat_list()`), I get an index error thrown by

```
if not x or len(x) < 1 or  n > len(x) or x[n] == None:
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code for my traversal methods is as follows:

```
def postorder(t):
    pass
    if t != None:
        postorder(t.get_left())
        postorder(t.get_right())
    print(t.get_data())

def pre_order(t):
    if t != None:
        print(t.get_data())
        pre_order(t.get_left())
        pre_order(t.get_right())

def in_order(t):
    pass
    if t != None:
        in_order(t.get_left())
        print(t.get_data())
        in_order(t.get_right())

def flat_list2(x,n):
  if not x or len(x) < 1 or  n > len(x) or x[n] == None:
    return None

   bt = BinaryTree( x[n] )
   bt.set_left( flat_list2(x, 2*n))
   bt.set_right(flat_list2(x, 2*n + 1))
 return bt
```

this is how i call flat_list2

```
flat_node_list = [None, 55, 24, 72, 8, 51, None, 78, None, None, 25]
bst = create_tree_from_flat_list2(flat_node_list,1)

    pre_order_nodes = pre_order(bst)

    in_order_nodes = in_order(bst)

    post_order_nodes = post_order(bst)

    print( pre_order_nodes)

    print( in_order_nodes)

    print( post_order_nodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should actually write three function that return iterators.  Let the caller decide whether a list is needed.  This is most easily done with generator functions.  In 3.4+, 'yield from` can by used instead of a for loop.

```
def in_order(t):
    if t != None:
        yield from in_order(t.get_left())
        yield t.get_data()
        yield from in_order(t.get_right())
```

Move the yield statement for the other two versions.

Comment: if not x or len(x) < 1 or  n > len(x) or x[n] == None:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I think you need to change `n > len(x)` to `n >= len(x)`.  Because python sequences are 0 based, for a sequence of length k, the largest legal index is k-1, not k.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I noticed that your indentation was inconsistent in the code block that you provided (fixed in revision). It is **critical** that you ensure that your indentation is consistent in `Python` or stuff will go south really quickly. Also, in the code below, I am assuming that you wanted your `t.get_data()` to still fall under `if t != None` in your `postorder(t)`, so I have indented as such below. And lastly, I noticed that your method names did not match the spec you listed in the question, so I have updated the method names below to be compliant with your spec (no `_` in the naming).

For getting the list, all you need to do is have your traversal methods return a list, and then `extend` your list at each level of the traversal with the other traversed values. This is done in lieu of printing the data.

```
def postorder(t):
    lst = []
    if t != None:
        lst.extend(postorder(t.get_left()))
        lst.extend(postorder(t.get_right()))
        lst.append(t.get_data())
    return lst

def preorder(t):
    lst = []
    if t != None:
        lst.append(t.get_data())
        lst.extend(preorder(t.get_left()))
        lst.extend(preorder(t.get_right()))
    return lst

def inorder(t):
    lst = []
    if t != None:
        lst.extend(inorder(t.get_left()))
        lst.append(t.get_data())
        lst.extend(inorder(t.get_right()))
    return lst
```

This will traverse to the full depths both left and right on each node and, depending on if it's `preorder`, `postorder`, or `inorder`, will append all the traversed elements in the order that they were traversed. Once this has occurred, it will return the properly ordered list to the next level up to get appended to its list. This will recurse until you get back to the root level.

Now, the `IndexError` coming from your `flat_list`, is probably being caused by trying to access `x[n]` when `n` could be equal to `len(x)`. Remember that lists/arrays in `Python` are indexed from `0`, meaning that the last element of the list would be `x[n-1]`, not `x[n]`.

So, to fix that, replace `x[n]` with `x[n-1]`. Like so:

```
def flat_list2(x,n):
    if not x or len(x) < 1 or n < 1 or n > len(x) or x[n-1] == None:
        return None

    bt = BinaryTree( x[n-1] )
    bt.set_left( flat_list2(x, 2*n))
    bt.set_right(flat_list2(x, 2*n + 1))
    return bt
```

Comment: hey its still printing out an error ill show my flat_list method

Comment: I'm getting an empty list as an output been trying to fix but can't figure out whats wrong

Comment: Pre = []
In = []
Post = []   thats what the output looks like atm

Comment: you have any idea why I'm still not getting the output ?? :/

Comment: @deans7 can I see how you call `flat_list2` please?

Comment: def flat_list2(x,n):
    if not x or len(x) < 1 or  n > len(x) or x[n] == None:
        return None
    
    bt = BinaryTree( x[n] )
    bt.set_left( create_tree_from_flat_list2(x, 2*n))
    bt.set_right( create_tree_from_flat_list2(x, 2*n + 1))
    return bt

Comment: sorry that must be hard to read should i edit my original code and add it there ??

Comment: its just when i add your flat list it changes my actual flat list output to None and gives the preorder, postorder and inorder function an empty list